# Java runtime exception while asking for IP address

Tags: java, mongodb, apache, tomcat, server

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package MyPack;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

/**
 *
 * @author OorjaTech
 */
public class Welcome extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Welcome
     */
    public Welcome() {
        initComponents();
        Dimension sd  = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setLocation(sd.width / 2 - this.getWidth()/ 2, sd.height / 2 - this.getHeight()/ 2); 
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 574));

        new JavaLib.LoadForm();
        jButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 102));
        jButton1.setText("Continue");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        new JavaLib.LoadForm();
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/MyPack/HealthyHeart.gif"))); // NOI18N

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 102));
        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel2.setText("Decision Support System In Diseases Using Naive Bayes");

        new JavaLib.LoadForm();
        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 102));
        jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel3.setText("And Its Application In Heart Diseases");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 102));
        jLabel4.setText("Enter IP Address:");

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jTextField1.setText("localhost");
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 976, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(194, 194, 194)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 384, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 68, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 326, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(26, 26, 26))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Settings.ipaddress = jTextField1.getText();
        this.setVisible(false);
        new LoginForm().setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Welcome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Welcome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Welcome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Welcome.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Welcome().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Whenever I run this file, I get a Java runtime exception error. Where am I going wrong? There is no compilation error and no stack-trace. My project uses mongo-db in the background . It ran fine like a year back and now it stopped running. The project also uses apache tomcat server which needs to be deployed before running the project. So i'm bit confused as to which part of the code i need to post here ? Sorry for the trouble... java is not my strong suite.

Comment: You did not post the error you got.

Comment: My bad. run:
.
..
...
Java Runtime Exception!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: This project contains a series of form. The current form asks user for IP address and then displays another form. But for some reason the current form is not displaying anything and gives the error Java Runtime Exception!

Comment: @Abdul_rehamanshaikh Could you please post the exact error you are getting? Please don't say it's a runtime exception. Please post is as you have posted the code.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the _entire_ error and stacktrace (if any).  Also, include any compiler warnings you saw.  Finally, the details you posted as comments should _also_ be in your question --- they won't be noticed down here in the chatter.

Comment: Please read "[ask]", then [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].  Unless you tell us what the problem is, we can only speculate about its solution.

Comment: I could post a dropbox link of my project if it helps @KevinJ.Chase

Comment: How do you know you're getting an exception?  Something, somewhere must be saying so... a console message, a Web server, an application server, some log file somewhere, whatever.  Include _that_, whatever it was.  (Also, is it specifically reporting a [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), or just some exception that happened when you tried to run it?)

Comment: Try to produce a [mcve].  Do you really think the various labels and fonts are causing the exception?  Remove them (on your test / staging server) and retry --- they're probably _not_ part of your question.  Try an empty frame, with no forms at all... whether it throws an exception or not, you'll learn _something_.  I highly recommend Eric Lippert's "[How To Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" for advice on isolating bugs like this.  It's one of several good articles listed at the bottom of the Help Center's "[ask]".

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Yep, it specifically says in the console Runtime Exception .Nothing more. No log files are generated. Nothing. I'll look into the post you suggested and get back to you.

Comment: I can't offer much more, since I have neither tomcat nor mongo-db.  You might want to [edit] your question to add one or both of them as tags, _if_ you come across some evidence that they're involved.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase i went through the post you suggested and i worked through that . This time i am getting an error [ connection refused : cannot connect ]

Comment: Again... [edit] your question!  It should include all the important details like the (complete) new error message, and _what you changed_ to produce that new error.  (They won't be seen down here in the comments.)  This could be a network problem, a permissions problem, a config problem in your middleware, firewall, or router... or even a typo'd IP address.  Keep working to narrow it down, so you can at least add appropriate tags, and keep track of what you've tried and what that achieved (even if it achieved nothing).  This is all basic troubleshooting work you'd have to do anyway.